# Unusual query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have this table:

```
      A                     B
1     Company Code          Year
2     61.490.561/0001-00    2018
3     61.490.561/0001-00    2017
4     61.490.561/0001-00    2016
5     84.586.205/0001-90    2018
6     84.586.205/0001-90    2017
7     84.586.205/0001-90    2016
8     01.009.357/0001-01    2017
9     01.009.357/0001-01    2015
10    01.009.354/0001-60    2017
11    01.009.354/0001-60    2016
12    01.009.355/0001-04    2016
13    01.009.355/0001-04    2015
14    04.185.877/0001-55    2018
15    04.185.877/0001-55    2017
16    04.185.877/0001-55    2016
    ...
```

I need to:

1. Check the last year for each of the Company Codes
2. Create a new table that will have five lines for each Company Code, the Year values will obey the following rationale: Last Year+1, Last Year+2, Last Year+3, Last Year+4, Last Year+5

In the example above, it would look like this:

```
      A                     B
1     Company Code          Year
2     61.490.561/0001-00    2023
3     61.490.561/0001-00    2022
4     61.490.561/0001-00    2021
5     61.490.561/0001-00    2020
6     61.490.561/0001-00    2019
7     84.586.205/0001-90    2023
8     84.586.205/0001-90    2022
9     84.586.205/0001-90    2021
10    84.586.205/0001-90    2020
11    84.586.205/0001-90    2019
12    01.009.357/0001-01    2022
13    01.009.357/0001-01    2021
14    01.009.357/0001-01    2020
15    01.009.357/0001-01    2019
16    01.009.357/0001-01    2018
17    01.009.354/0001-60    2022
18    01.009.354/0001-60    2021
19    01.009.354/0001-60    2020
20    01.009.354/0001-60    2019
21    01.009.354/0001-60    2018
22    01.009.355/0001-04    2021
23    01.009.355/0001-04    2020
24    01.009.355/0001-04    2019
25    01.009.355/0001-04    2018
26    01.009.355/0001-04    2017
27    04.185.877/0001-55    2023
28    04.185.877/0001-55    2022
29    04.185.877/0001-55    2021
30    04.185.877/0001-55    2020
31    04.185.877/0001-55    2019
```

I tried using query but this one seems quite advanced for my skills. How can I make a start on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically one of my first attempts on Google Spreadsheets.

What if you have in a second tab (Sheet2) in `A2`:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$16),ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/5))
```

In cel `B2`:

```
=MAXIFS(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$16,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$16,A2)+COUNTIF(A2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA(A:A)-1),A2)
```

And drag both down...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:B1; SORT({
 QUERY(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), , 1), 
 SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), {1, 2}, 0))), "select Col1,Col2+1 label Col2+1''", 0);
 QUERY(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), , 1), 
 SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), {1, 2}, 0))), "select Col1,Col2+2 label Col2+2''", 0);
 QUERY(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), , 1), 
 SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), {1, 2}, 0))), "select Col1,Col2+3 label Col2+3''", 0);
 QUERY(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), , 1), 
 SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), {1, 2} ,0))) ,"select Col1,Col2+4 label Col2+4''", 0);
 QUERY(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), , 1), 
 SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 0), {1, 2}, 0))), "select Col1,Col2+5 label Col2+5''", 0)}, 
 1, 1, 2, 0)})
```

[image: 0]